# cp -u is illegal on mac. What are the alternatives?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, osx-lion

I have a MacbookPro Lion, and I have tried to archive my files that is tried to copy and overwrite if the source is newer than the destination. I tried the following command

```
cp -u source destination
```

but it says, -u is illegal. I also did not find --update or -u in the `man cp`.

Can you please help, what can I do in this situation?

Comment: Can you please explain why this is not a legitimate question so I can work on it?

Comment: It's not illegitimate, it's just in the wrong place. It would be fine on the Unix or Superusers site.

Comment: Ah, thanks! ok, can I move it there somehow directly or I registrate there, put it up again and delete this?

Comment: You needn't (and can't!) move it yourself. Three people have already flagged it for migration to superuser.com. It will probably be migrated there soon (moderators can do that). You should get a notification when that happens, and you can then login to that site and set up an account linked to your existing stackoverflow account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-nt` condition:

```
[[ source/$file -nt destination/$file ]] && cp source/$file destination/$file
```

Just run this for all files (via a loop or through `find`).

Answer (score 0):

I have installed GNU Coreutils with MacPorts by

```
sudo ports install coreutils findutils
```

findutils are not necessary but [they suggested to install it too](http://www.sgenomics.org/~jtang/blog/posts/Enabling_the_gnu_coreutils_and_findutils_with_macports_on_OSX/).

I followed the idea from Keith Thompson, (cudos!). It works greatly, the "advanced" copy command is now:

```
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/cp
```

It does not have a man page, but has a long, man-style help with the `--help` option.

---

I have also copied the question to the superuser page, with some funny story... but I could not delete it here, apologises.